# EJB Client has issues when Server goes down

Tags: java, ejb, rmi

First of all, I'm not that knowledgeable on EJB's, just trying to understand what's going on here.

I have a service that calls a backend via EJB interface.  If the backend goes down, then the service starts throwing the following exception while the backend is down and then after it comes back up it continues to occasionally throughout the next day.  However, it is intermittent.  More than not everything works fine, but occasionally we get the error below.  It's like we have some ejb connections to that backend that get messed up when the backend goes down and some that don't.

(Changing the method/interface name as they are specific to my project)

```
Remote EJB method: someMethod called on interface: com.someInterface failed.
Cause: java.rmi.NoSuchObjectException: The object identified by: '301' could not be found.
Either it was has not been exported or it has been collected by the distributed garbage collector.
```

I'm assuming when the backend goes down, the EJB connection is no longer valid and it's just taking a while to clear out that bad connection?

Any suggestions, ideas?  Would appreciate help just understanding what's going on better.

Answer (score 0):

The message is pretty clear. The stub you are using to talk to the EJB is stale, i.e. it refers to an object that no longer exists, whether via DGC, deliberate unexporting, or entire server restart. The mitigation here is to re-acquire the stub, via whatever means you did that, and try again, once.